# Interpretation of the stochastic integral as a wealth process

Tags: probability, finance, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

> An agent has wealth $X(t)$ at time $t$ and invests an amount $\Delta(t)$ of money into a stock $S(t)$ given by
>   $$
> dS(t) = \mu S(t)\, dt + \sigma S(t) \, dB(t).
> $$
>   In other words, the wealth process has representation $X(t) = (\Delta/S \bullet S)(t)$.

I don't understand why $X(t) = (\Delta/S \bullet S)(t)$. For me, it would be more intuitive to have $X(t) = (\Delta \bullet S)(t)$. Here $\bullet$ denotes the stochastic integral.

Comment: Suppose you buy the stock at time $t_0$. Then you can buy $\Delta(t_0)/S(t_0)$ units of stocks. And if you keep holding the stock, the wealth at future time $t$ will be $\Delta(t_0)/S(t_0) \times S(t)$

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. But other books write $dX(t) = \Delta(t) dS(t)$. Why is this the same?